# Android Parse query from both cloud and local datastore

Tags: android, parse-platform

Is it possible to query from both the parse cloud and the local datastore? I've tried doing so with a compound query, but it only returns results from the cloud. The query is used in a ParseQueryAdapter so only one query can be returned. Each query works separately but not when combined through ParseQuery.or().

```
    public GameScoreQueryAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<GameScore>(){
        public ParseQuery<GameScore> create () {
            ParseQuery<GameScore> query = new ParseQuery<GameScore>("GameScore");
            query.whereEqualTo("user", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());

            ParseQuery<GameScore> localQuery = new ParseQuery<GameScore>("GameScore");
            localQuery.whereEqualTo("user", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
            localQuery.fromLocalDatastore();

            List<ParseQuery<GameScore>> queryList = new ArrayList<ParseQuery<GameScore>>();
            queryList.add(query);
            queryList.add(localQuery);

            ParseQuery<GameScore> compoundQuery = ParseQuery.or(queryList);

            return compoundQuery;
        }
    });
}
```